# please provide the location of the "\msdev\include " directory. to download

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, download

I installed EDG compiler in Windows i.e in "win32". After installation I am trying to run this simple code:

```
   using namespace std;
   int main()
    {
     cout<<"OM";
     return 0;
    }
```

I am getting errors like unidentified cout, etc

Actually I didn't give path dev libraries : there in read me file it is to give. Later I did gave path to libraries(VS C++ 2010)

Please provide me the MSDEV /include header files to download.

Please provide the location of the "\msdev\include" directory to download.

**edit:** in readme file they gave "No stream

I/O library is included; this is just very basic support."

if we gave iostream.h also .it shows ..many erros ..regarding that?

**EDIT:** Otherwise any one

Provide link to download EDG compiler (C++) for windows.Free ware

who already working successively with this....

Comment: It looks like you're missing `#include <iostream>` ?

Comment: @Paul R : no need of I/O library

Comment: `cout` *is* I/O. you can't use `cout` unless you `#include <iostream>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see from their page, EDG do not provide a full compiler, but [only a front-end](http://www.edg.com/index.php?location=faq_q1_whatsell); it does not include neither an optimizer/code generator neither a standard library. You simply cannot use just EDG to produce an executable.

You can find several free implementations of the C++ standard library (e.g. [libstdc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/) from GNU, to which I suppose you should add [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/) for the C library subset), but without at least a code-generator backend all you can get from the front-end is the AST of the code gave in input.

Moreover, EDG C++ it's not free, neither it is sold to individuals; EDG license only the source code and [only to corporations](http://www.edg.com/index.php?location=faq_q2_cost) for a 40K$-250K$ price range. The links you're asking in your question would be illegal.

If you just need a compiler for Windows, there are several great alternatives, both free and not-free, some are listed e.g. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1154517/c-compiler-for-windows).